# Checking the checkbox is not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

This is a simple TO-DO app in react in which `App.js` takes data from `TodosData.js` and the list is shown with the component `TodoItem.js`. Now the checkboxes and data can be viewed when rendered. But when I click on the checkbox it doesn't work. I tried console logging `handleChange` function which seems to work. It seems like there maybe problems inside the `handleChange` function which I can't figure out.

I am following a freecodecamp tutorial on YT and I also checked it several times but can't find the problem here.

> **App.js** code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'
import todosData from './todosData'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super ()
    this.state = { todos: todosData }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
      })
      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(itemEach => <TodoItem key = {itemEach.id} itemEach = {itemEach}
      handleChange = {this.handleChange} />)
    return (
      <div className = "todo-list">
        {todoItems}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

> **TodoItem.js** code:

```
import React from 'react';

function TodoItem(props) {
  return(
    <div className = "todo-item">
      <input type = "checkbox"
        checked={props.itemEach.completed}
        onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.itemEach.id)}
      />
      <p>{props.itemEach.text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoItem
```

> **TodosData.js** code:

```
const todosData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Take out the trash",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Grocery shopping",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Clearn gecko tank",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "Mow lawn",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "Catch up on Arrested Development",
    completed: false
  }
]

export default todosData
```

Is there a better way to implement this? This way of doing checkbox seems quite complicated for a beginner like myself. Also how can I improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state in your `handleChange` function. Hence it gets the `prevState` twice. Once for the original previous state, next for the update that you make inside the `handleChange`.

You can probably lose the reference, by spreading the `todo` from state like this.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
    const resTodo = { ...todo };
    if (todo.id === id) {
      resTodo.completed = !resTodo.completed;
    }
    return resTodo;
  });
  return {
    todos: updatedTodos
  };
});
```

Here's a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-lewin-o3qxb)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now it's working. Can you please explain more on this line- `const resTodo = { ...todo };`.

Comment: @FarhanBinAmin [Read this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/), should help